# Why does QtGraphicalEffects cause changes to the Render Buffer each frame?

Tags: performance, qt, qml

I am having some pretty big performance issues using a `ListView` where all `delegate`s are using a `RectangularGlow` as their backdrop. Looks very nice :-)

The only problem is, it slows down FPS drastically, and I do not understand why the Render Buffer has to get changes every frame in order to draw it.

Here's an example.

A flat `Rectangle` with a `RectangularGlow` behind it:
[image]

Looking at the same scene using `QSG_VISUALIZE=changes`:
[image]

Clearly showing that it's happening every frame.

Is this working as intended? If so, basically any form of cheating (i.e. making a static `BorderImage` looking like this `RectangularGlow`) would always be the better solution over `QtGraphicalEffects`?

I even have `cached: true` on the glow, to no avail.

What gives?

Source:

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    RectangularGlow {
        id: outerGlow

        height: 400
        width: 500

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        cached: true

        glowRadius: 10
        spread: 1

        opacity: 1

        color: "#20000000"

        cornerRadius: glowRadius
    }

    Rectangle {
        height: 400
        width: 500
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```